# Configure Multi-tenant for reporting service integrated mode

Tags: reporting-services, 2016, multi-tenancy

Could any one help to configure multi-tenant for reporting service integrated mode with SharePoint 2016?

I want to know the architecture and security consideration , the prerequisites , the configuration steps ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSRS does not support multi-tenancy and in fact will not work.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219068(v=sql.130).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer,in this case, should you advise me in multi-tenant environment how i can use reporting service ?  Is it will need more special configuration or a normal configuration ? how it will work over multi-tenant environment ?

Comment: You would need a separate instance of SSRS for each tenant.